# I want to know about the vulnerability of Secret key passed as config in express-session

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, express-session

we pass an object that has a secret key's value right in front -->

```js
app.use(session({
  secret: 'keyboard cat',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  cookie: { secure: true }
})
```

I want to know if It's a good practice to have that secret key out in the open or I should pass it through an environment variable

Comment: I find asking "if it's good practice to have a secret key out in the open" quite humorous...

Answer (score 1):

Yes you should put that key in an environment variable, maybe in a `.env` file and use the `dotenv` package to grab it as a variable from your server-side javascript.

The security issue with having your key as plaintext in that javascript file is if you commit this to source control, then anyone with access to your repo has access to that secret key as well.